# XML extracting parsing with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to parse some XML data from this url: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml , return the Count value and sum the extracted values.

```
import urllib as ur
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = input(('Enter location: '))
print'Retrieving:', url

data = ur.urlopen(url).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
counts = tree.findall('.//count')

print('Count: ', sum(counts))
#print('Sum: ', sum_all)
```

I understand there is some basic issue here, but I've been trying and failing to amend my code without success. I am receiving a TypeError as follows:

```
Enter location: 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
Retrieving: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extracting_xml.py", line 11, in <module>
    print('Count: ', sum(counts))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Element'
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular: an excerpt from your XML document that you are trying to parse and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is in the summation `sum(counts)`. Instead you should do:

```
sum([int(el.text) for el in counts])
```

As the exception indicates you are trying to sum up found nodes of type `Element` which do not have addition operator defined. The nodes contain plain integers so converting the text of the node to `int` and then summing up is what you need to do.

Should you have floats in your nodes then you would use `float` constructor.

Comment: perfect, thank you! just so I can make sure I understand, this amendment is 1. converting elements to integers 2. for the elements in counts?

Comment: Converting `text` value of object of type `Element` to `int`. In this [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) it is variable `el`.

Comment: @Jon: If my answer resolves your problem please mark it (gray tick on the left of the answer).